# Insert newlines with vim

Tags: vim, newlines

How to insert newlines in vim?

For example in a file containing

```
test-classes; classes; xmlunit-1.3.jar
```

I am looking for the vim equivalent of sed command

```
sed -i 's/; /\n/g' classpath
```

to obtain

```
test-classes
classes
xmlunit-1.3.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right, just use `\r` instead of `\n`:

```
:%s/; /\r/g
```

Comment: For non-vim variants of `vi`, you'd probably need to use a literal newline character instead of `\r` - which you can obtain by typing `Ctrl-V Ctrl-M`. This will display as `^M`.